# Dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-93-generic

Tags: apt, grub2, package-management, dpkg

Unfortunately, `apt-get` always throws errors due to the `3.13.0-93` kernel package and I would like to get rid of them.

Also, there seems something broken with my grub configuration, since the boatloader only shows entries for

- 3.13.0-93
- 3.13.0-93 (recovery)
- memtest

If you need more information, I am happy to provide them.

> $ uname -a

```
Linux Z 3.13.0-93-generic #140-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jul 18 21:21:05 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

> $ sudo apt-get install -f

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-3.13.0-93-generic (3.13.0-93.140) ...
Internal Error: Could not find image (/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-93-generic)
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                                                                                                                                    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                             dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-93-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-3.13.0-93-generic:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-93-generic depends on linux-image-3.13.0-93-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.13.0-93-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-93-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-3.13.0-93-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.13.0-93-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-3.13.0-93-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-93-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 3.13.0.93.100); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

> $ sudo update-initramfs -u -k all

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-93-generic
grep: /boot/config-3.13.0-93-generic: No such file or directory
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-92-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-88-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-68-generic
grep: /boot/config-3.2.0-68-generic: No such file or directory
```

> $ sudo update-grub2

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-92-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-92-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-91-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-88-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-88-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-63-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-63-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-62-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-62-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-61-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-61-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-59-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-59-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-46-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-46-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-45-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-61-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-61-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-60-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-60-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-59-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-59-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-58-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-58-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-57-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-57-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-56-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-56-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-55-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-55-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-54-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-54-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-53-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-53-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-29-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-29-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-27-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-27-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-26-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-26-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-25-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-25-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
```

**Edit:** `autoremove` yielded the following result, while the output of `apt-get install -f` stayed nearly the same after `autoremove` (same dpkg error, only less repetitions).

> $ sudo apt-get autoremove

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-headers-3.13.0-92 linux-headers-3.13.0-92-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-92-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-92-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 4 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 272 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 528974 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-headers-3.13.0-92-generic (3.13.0-92.139) ...
Removing linux-headers-3.13.0-92 (3.13.0-92.139) ...
Removing linux-image-extra-3.13.0-92-generic (3.13.0-92.139) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-92-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-92-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.13.0-92-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-92-generic
Error! Could not locate dkms.conf file.
File:  does not exist.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-92-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-92-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-92-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.13.0-92-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-92-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.13.0-92-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-92-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-extlinux 3.13.0-92-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-92-generic
P: Checking for EXTLINUX directory... found.
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-61-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-60-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-59-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-58-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-57-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-56-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-55-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-54-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-53-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-29-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-27-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-26-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-25-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-95-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-92-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-91-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-88-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-63-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-62-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-61-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-59-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-46-generic.efi.signed...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-46-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-45-generic...
P: Installing debian theme... done.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-92-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-92-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-95-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-95-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-92-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-92-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-91-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-88-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-88-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-63-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-63-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-62-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-62-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-61-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-61-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-59-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-59-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-46-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-46-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-45-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-61-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-61-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-60-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-60-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-59-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-59-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-58-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-58-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-57-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-57-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-56-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-56-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-55-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-55-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-54-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-54-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-53-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-53-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-29-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-29-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-27-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-27-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-26-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-26-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-25-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-25-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
Removing linux-image-3.13.0-92-generic (3.13.0-92.139) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/prerm.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/prerm.d/dkms 3.13.0-92-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-92-generic
dkms: removing: fglrx-core 15.201 (3.13.0-92-generic) (x86_64)

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  fglrx-core
Version: 15.201
Kernel:  3.13.0-92-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

fglrx.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/3.13.0-92-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod.....

DKMS: uninstall completed.
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-92-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-92-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-92-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-extlinux 3.13.0-92-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-92-generic
P: Checking for EXTLINUX directory... found.
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-61-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-60-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-59-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-58-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-57-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-56-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-55-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-54-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-53-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-29-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-27-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-26-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-25-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-95-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-91-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-88-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-63-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-62-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-61-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-59-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-46-generic.efi.signed...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-46-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-45-generic...
P: Updating /boot/extlinux/linux.cfg...
P: Installing debian theme... done.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-92-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-92-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-95-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-95-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-91-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-88-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-88-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-63-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-63-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-62-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-62-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-61-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-61-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-59-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-59-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-46-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-46-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-45-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-61-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-61-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-60-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-60-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-59-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-59-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-58-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-58-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-57-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-57-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-56-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-56-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-55-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-55-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-54-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-54-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-53-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-53-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-29-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-29-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-27-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-27-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-26-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-26-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-25-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-25-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
Setting up linux-image-3.13.0-93-generic (3.13.0-93.140) ...
Internal Error: Could not find image (/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-93-generic)
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-93-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-3.13.0-93-generic:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-93-generic depends on linux-image-3.13.0-93-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.13.0-93-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-93-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                         E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Try running `sudo apt autoremove`

Comment: Maybe it's time to remove some old kernels...

Comment: I don't think the kernels are actually installed: `dpkg -l 'linux-[ihs]*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\([-0-9]*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d'` : 
linux-headers-3.13.0-95
linux-headers-3.13.0-95-generic
linux-image-3.13.0-95-generic
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-95-generic

Comment: I ended up with reinstalling the complete OS.